# Determine the scalarform of a plane that contains the line $L$ and goes through the midpoint $P$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I need to determine the scalarform of a plane that contain $L:\begin{cases} 3x + 4y + z = 5 \\
x − y = −6 \end{cases}$ and goes through the midpoint of $(1, 1, 2)$ and $(3, 1, 4)$.

My try solving this. Call the midpoint $P$ then $P:(2,1,3)$. The direction vector $v$ of the line is obtained by the crossproduct of the normal of each plane, so $(3,4,1)\times (1,-1,0)=(1,1,-7)$. Thus we have $x+y-7z=d$ and putting in $(2,1,3)$ gives $x+y-7z=20$. But the answer is $13x + 36y + 7z = 83$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not correct. $x+y−7z=-18$ is the plane which is *orthogonal* to the line $L$ and passes through $(2,1,3)$.

Notice that all the planes which *contain* the line $L$ ([sheaf of planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_of_planes)) are given by
$$a(3x+4y+z-5)+b(x-y+6)=0\quad \text{with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$}.$$
We have to find $a,b$ such that the above equation is satisfied for $(x,y,z)=(2,1,3)$:
$$a(6+4+3-5)+b(2-1+6)=0\implies 8a+7b=0.$$
Therefore may take $a=7$ and $b=-8$:
$$7(3x+4y+z-5)-8(x-y+6)=13x + 36y + 7z - 83=0$$
and your answer is confirmed.

Comment: Nice a couple of questions though. Where do my approach fail. Is the vector product actually the direction vector of the line but I incorrectly put it in normal form. And also why are all planes that contains $L$ given by your equation?

Comment: @perpersson Your plane is orthogonal to $L$! My equation is a plane and it is satisfied by the points along $L$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_of_planes

Comment: I think I understand sheaf of planes is just that one need one more point to fix the plane. But I don't understand how your equations describes the sheaf of planes.

Comment: If a point is along $L$ then $\begin{cases} 3x + 4y + z - 5=0\\
x − y +6=0 \end{cases}$ and therefore $a(3x+4y+z-5)+b(x-y+6)=0$.

Comment: So it is an equivalence relation between the equation you obtained and the linear equation system. $\begin{cases} 3x+4y+z-5=0\\ x-y+6=0\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} a(3x+4y+z-5)=0\\ b(x-y+6)=0\end{cases} \iff a(3x+4y+z-5)+ b(x-y+6)=0$. So no matter $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ the equation will always satisfy the linear equation system for the line.

Comment: It's just $\implies$. The plane contains the line, it is not equal.

Comment: Finally I think I understand. The set of solutions of the linear equation is a subset of the set of solutions of $a(3x+4y+z−5)+b(x−y+6)=0$.

Comment: And I'm guessing it is somewhat trivial that any plane that contains $L$ must have the form $a(3x+4y+z−5)+b(x−y+6)=0$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}. Because if there exists a plane that doesn't have that form then it can't satisfy the linear equation.

Comment: @perpersson Yes, exactly. I answered also another question of yours...

Answer (score 1):

$(1, 1, -7)$ is the direction vector of the line of intersection of the two given planes (line $L$).  It is not the normal vector of the required plane.

In addition to the direction vector of line $L$, you need a point on that line.  Such a point can be found by Gauss-Jordan elimination of the two linear equations of the two planes

$ 3 x + 4 y + z = 5 \hspace{25pt}(1) $

$ x - y = -6 \hspace{25pt}(2)$

Set $x = 0$, and solve the resulting system for $y$ and $z$

$ 4 y + z = 5 \hspace{25pt}(1')$

$ - y = - 6 \hspace{25pt}(2')$

So $(2')$ implies $ y = 6 $ and then $(1')$ implies $z = -19 $

So a point on line $L$ is $Q=(0, 6, -19) $

The midpoint you found to be $P = (2,1,3)$

Calculate the vector

$QP = P - Q = (2, -5, 22) $

And you have the direction vector of line $L$, namely,

$ V = (1, 1, -7)$

Hence, the normal to the plane is

$ N = QP \times V = (2, -5, 22) \times (1, 1, -7) = (13, 36, 7 ) $

The equation of the plane is

$ N \cdot (p - Q) = 0 $

$ (13, 36, 7) \cdot ((x,y,z) - (0, 6, -19) ) = 0 $

which simplifies to

$ 13 z + 36 y + 7 z - 83 = 0 $